# Calling JS function multiple times with different callbacks executes only the last callback every time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that I call multiple times passing it different callback function as an argument. I need to execute the passed callback when the function is called, however it always executes the last callback as many times as the function is called.

Here is an example:

```
var loadCallback = 'undefined';
function callMe (callback) {
    loadCallback = callback;
    // some code here

    loadCallback();
}
```

Then I'm calling it 3 times like this:

```
callMe(function(){
    var test1 = function () {console.log('test1')}
    test1();

    // another code that has to be executed, but only the one from the last call is executed every time
});

callMe(function(){
    var test2 = function () {console.log('test2')}
    test2();

    // another code that has to be executed, but only the one from the last call is executed every time
});

callMe(function(){
    var test3 = function () {console.log('test3')}
    test3();

    // another code that has to be executed, but only the one from the last call is executed every time
});
```

In an SO snippet:

```js
var loadCallback;

function callMe(callback) {
  loadCallback = callback;
  loadCallback();
}

callMe(function() {
  var test1 = function() {
    console.log('test1')
  }
  test1();
});

callMe(function() {
  var test2 = function() {
    console.log('test2')
  }
  test2();
});

callMe(function() {
  var test3 = function() {
    console.log('test3')
  }
  test3();
});
```

And in the console I see:

```
test3
test3
test3
```

instead of:

```
test1
test2
test3
```

Why is this happening and how to fix it? I'm searching in Google for over an hour now and I can't find a solution.

Comment: *Then I'm calling it 3 times like this* - there's only one call there - how are you calling it three times?  3 times in quick succession? or 3 times in a loop? or setup and then call?  Your "call it 3 times like this" seems to only call it with hardcoded `test1` text, so unclear where test2/test3 would come from.

Comment: I edited the question. I'm calling it 3 times from different parts of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  How you call it is very important.  I've put your code, as you've provided that you state you call it, in a snippet in the question and, you'll see, it works absolutely fine.  Perhaps you could update the snippet to show the code you're using where it doesn't work?

Comment: Here's a version running in a loop:  https://jsfiddle.net/tmLpj7a1/   Because `loadCallback` is called immediately, it's not using the global `loadCallback` (given the code provided) after it's been setup an doesn't suffer from closure issues.

Comment: Yes, it is. I found my mistake and fixed it. Thank you for commenting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you declare `loadCallback` outside of the function. As such you overwrite that assignment in every iteration of your loop.

To fix this just use the `callback` argument directly. Also note that you don't need to wrap the callback function multiple times when you define it. Try this:

```js
function callMe(callback) {
  // other logic...
  callback();
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
  callMe(function() {
    console.log('test' + i)
  });
}
```

Comment: Your code works, however when I use the `callback` argument directly I get an error (3 times) `TypeError:+callback+is+not+a+function`. However `console.log('Callback: ' + typeof callback);` in the beginning of the function says it is a function, but above where I'm calling it says it's undefined. I'm confused.

Comment: I made a huge mistake in the other code of the function. I call it recursively and didn't passed the callback argument, that's why it was undefined. Now it works and I'm accepting this answer.